# Date sqlite3 in a CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am following a tutorial and encountered the following code. What does `date` mean here? I thought date was not supported in sqlite3.

```
create table log_date (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    entry_date date not null
);
```

Comment: Well, its a tutorial on Flask. Perhaps, the sqlite knowledge was assumed. All I understand from this is... create table called log_date. Create 2 columns, one called ID  that has to be an integer, it is assigned a unique key and updates (w.e  that means). Add another column called entry date and it must not be null. I still am lost and do not understand what date is. No the tutorial does not explain this part.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite [does not have a `DATE` type](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype), but that doesn't mean it won't let you use it in a `CREATE TABLE` and then use a different data type underneath.

`DATE` is converted to `NUMERIC` as described in [Affinity Name Examples](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples).

There's a [prioritized set of rules](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity) to determine what a not-formally-supported type gets converted to, and `DATE`/`DATETIME` both work out to `NUMERIC`.

Answer (score 0):

**date** is the type affinity, which due to SQLite's flexibility is actually a type affinity of **NUMERIC** (see 3.1 in the link below for how the type affinity is determined).

The type affinity specified can be virtually anything (not KEYWORDS and there are limitations in regards to values in parenthesises). A type affinity of **grUmpleStiltskin** is even usable (again gets converted to the **NUMERIC** bucket).

**However**, due to SQLite's flexibility any type of data can be stored in any type of column *(with the exception of a column that is an alias of the rowid (as is your **id** column as it has `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`), an alias of the rowid column, or the rowid column itself can only store an Integer value (64 bit signed))*.

You may wish to have a read of [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

> one called ID that has to be an integer, it is assigned a unique key
>   and updates (w.e that means).

As said because you have INTEGER PRIMARY KEY then the **id** column is an alias of the normally hidden **rowid** column. If no value is specified when inserting a row then SQLite will attempt to assign a unique 64 bit integer value. It will typically be 1 greater than the highest existing rowid.

AUTOINCREMENT, as you have coded, introduces a rule/constraint that only values higher than the highest used (even if deleted) rowid value. AUTOINCREMENT can only be used for columns that are aliases of the rowid column can be used.

**However**, the very first sentence in [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) is :-

- > **The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
  >   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
  >   usually not needed.**